# Laravel - como autorizar determinada ação?

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma pequena aplicação escrita com Laravel 5.3, em determinado ponto realizo uma verificação para saber se o usuário logado tem permissão para editar/alterar ou apagar determinado post:

```
if(!$post = Auth::user()->posts()->where('id', $id)->first()) {
    return redirect()->route('post.index')
            ->with(['status' => 'danger', 'mensagem' => 'Este post não te pertence!']);
}
```

Como posso criar uma política e utilizar está de modo que, o administrador (super admin) e o dono do post sejam os únicos a terem permissão sobre o post?

Comment: COmo diferencias o admin do user?

Comment: O super admin tem id = 1, ou seja, ele é o primeiro registro presente no banco de dados.

Comment: E como identifica que o dono é o dono do post?